Cross-Browser Method to Determine Vertical Scroll 50% in JavaScript
There is such a code. I need to execute the js code when the page is scrolled by 50% 1 time.
But my code is executed every time I move.
Help me fix it
document.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
const height = window.scrollY / (document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight)

if ( height > 0.5 ) {
console.log('End 50');

}
})

I tried return 0; and break

If you only want this to execute 1 time, remove the listener after it runs.

How can I add an event for a one time click to a function?

Thanks!
Although this part doesn't work correctly for me, I was able to write working code for myself.:
<script>   

document.addEventListener('scroll', halfPageScroll);
function halfPageScroll(e) {
const height = window.scrollY / (document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight)

if ( height > 0.5 ) {
console.log('End 50');
 document.removeEventListener('scroll', halfPageScroll);
}
}
</script>


Please specify what part of the OP's code didn't work, and what you changed it to

First, get the page height:
var pageHeight = Math.max(document.body.scrollHeight, document.body.offsetHeight, 
                       document.documentElement.clientHeight, document.documentElement.scrollHeight, document.documentElement.offsetHeight);

Now, get 50% of it:
var halfPage = pageHeight / 50;

Now listen to the scroll event:
document.addEventListener('scroll', halfPageScroll);
function halfPageScroll(e) {
    if(window.scrollY >= halfPage) {
        alert('50% scrolled');

        // Remove event listener so that this only fires the first time a user scrolls 50% of the page
        document.removeEventListener('scroll', halfPageScroll);
    }
}

Note: This approach may not work if the page has dynamically loaded content. Because the page height can increase as the user scrolls down the page, so it is difficult to determine the full page height.

Thanks!
Although this part doesn't work correctly for me, I was able to write working code for myself.

I think this part of the code doesn't work the way it should "var halfPage = pageHeight / 50;"
